# Javascript resource file (.js) vs resource file (.resx)

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, knockout.js, resources

I'm wondering what's the best solution in my case.
I got the following setup:

- ASP page with usercontrols
- Knockout.js
- WCF services called by js
- Multilangual

I'm doing json back and forth calls between my webservice and my usercontrol. Since the application needs to be multilangual, I thought about storing some of my resources in a javascript file (sent from the webservice and messages to users), so that when for example an error is thrown in the service, I return a error code (=ID) (example: "TECH_4125") and get the resource from my javascript file in the correct language, with help of the lcid.

Since javascript files are stored in cache, I thought this would be the best way to do this (to improve performance??? -> but of course you have more resources than needed on each page) Another reason to use this is because we can reuse some of the resources on other pages.

**Example of a javascript resources**

- resources-2067.js

  ```
  var MessageCode={"NOT_0003":{"Label":"Geen resultaten gevonden","Display":"1 - Geen resultaten gevonden"}};
  ```
- resources-2057.js

  ```
  var MessageCode={"NOT_0003":{"Label":"No results found","Display":"1- No results found"}};
  ```
- resources-1031.js

  ```
  var MessageCode={"NOT_0003":{"Label":"Aucun résultat trouvé","Display":"1- Aucun résultat trouvé"}};
  ```

(+ I'm getting my resource label with for example: MessageCode.NOT_0003.Label)

What would you prefer and why?

Comment: I can't imagine nobody knows this?

Answer (score 1):

As a first principle I think you should use things for what they are made for. JavaScript files are for JavaScript code and not data storage.

If you have not many of these, then I guess it's ok to create a config.js where you store you generic error messages (When errors are about your Javascript code).

But in your case you seem to have many cultures you are supporting and for each you have many error messages. Furthermore your errors are about database data such as contact not found etc.

So you need to Send those errors as a part of your Ajax response to the client. Your JavaScript then should be passing those error messages to the user.

You can determine what culture those responses should be in using either user Id, visited country url etc. which is an application wide constant and can be mapped to a culture.

What you want to end up with is a JavaScript that preferably has no knowledge of culture but simply passing relevant error messages based on your error codes.

Conclusion:

keep your resx files or store in db as return appropriate error message to the client based on the culture without involving the client side.

Comment: Why does Microsoft "recommend" it then (by creating a walkthrough) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398935.aspx

Comment: That's a tiny object with some error messages. What you are asking sounds like you want to use js file as a storage mechanism similar to resource files. Which is highly against separation of concern

Comment: Furthermore in that example we only have English, so a simple mapping from error code to a string value for user applies. but in your case we have different languages which makes the object larger and gives the assignment of the correct language value to the interface the job of the front end.

Comment: I know, I should update my example, there should be multiple javascript files (one for each language)